# Trying to retrieve records with data in one column that doesn't match data from another column

Tags: ms-access

So I have a table of records in Access (example below), where I want to retrieve the records where an Entry Date occurs on a date that a Transaction Date that does not occur for a given person. There also may days that a transaction may occur, but there is no Entry Date. I am only concerned here with the rows that have an Entry Date/Time.

```
Transaction Date/Time    First Name    Last Name   Entry Date/Time
07/02/2014 11:45 PM      Sally         Smith       07/14/2014 12:17 PM
07/02/2014 07:34 AM      John          Foobar      07/02/2014 01:34 PM
07/03/2014 08:56 AM      Sally         Smith       07/02/2014 08:00 AM
07/03/2015 09:33 AM      John          Foobar
```

What I would be interested in retrieving here is the first transaction for Sally Smith, because its Entry Date occurs on a day that Sally Smith had no Transactions.

I am trying to build this utilizing a Query where the data is retrieved from SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sub query that checks whether there's no record having an entry date that matches a transaction date.
Use the Format function to check on the date part only.

PS I'd include a PersonID primary key as the combination of first and last name is not unique.

Originally, in the sub query FORMAT(b.[Entry Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') and Format(a.[Transaction Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') were used.
I made an error while copy and pasting.
Entry Date should refer to table alias a and Transaction Date should refer to table alias b.
I adjusted the original query.

```
SELECT a.[Transaction Date/Time], a.[First Name], a.[Last Name], a.[Entry Date/Time]
FROM yourtable a
WHERE a.[Entry Date/Time] IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM yourtable AS b
WHERE FORMAT(a.[Entry Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') = Format(b.[Transaction Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy')
AND b.[First Name] = a.[First Name]
AND b.[Last Name] = a.[Last Name]
)
```

Comment: About as far as I had got was something similar to what you suggested:

`SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE FORMAT([Table1].[Entry Date/Time],'mm/dd/yyyy')
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT([Trans  Date/Time],'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM Table1)
AND [Entry Date/Time] IS NOT NULL;`

However, this is limited to entries on days that NO transactions took place for any person. I should have been more clear, but I need to match the entries against ALL Transaction days. Your results seem to do what is almost intended, but do not exclude the results of matching transactions that do not have an entry date. @Rene

Comment: Could you provide some examples that show that my query does not as expected?

Comment: `Trans Date/Time, First Name, Last Name, Entry Date/Time,
07/11/2016 05:00 PM, Jane, Doe, 07/12/2016 09:09 AM`

Where in Table 1 exists: `07/12/2016 05:49 PM, Jane, Doe, NULL` 

They are all similar in that the results are not excluding the NULL Entry date and times. So if Jane Doe has Transactions on 07/10/2016 (entered on 07/11/2016), 07/12/2016 (entered on (07/13/2016), 07/13/2016 (NULL entry), and 07/14/2016 (NULL ENTRY)...The 07/10/2016 result should be the only one selected as it does not have a NULL Entry and was entered on a date that no Transaction occurred (07/11/2016). @Rene

Comment: Okay, I will be able to test slightly better later this week, but I think a slight modification is giving me what I want: `SELECT a.[Trans  Date/Time], a.[Child  First Name], a.[Child  Last Name], a.[Entry Date/Time]
FROM Table1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM Table1 AS b
WHERE (FORMAT(b.[Entry Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') = Format(a.[Trans  Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy')
OR b.[Entry Date/Time] IS NULL)
AND b.[Child  First Name] = a.[Child  First Name]
AND b.[Child  Last Name] = a.[Child  Last Name]
)
AND a.[Entry Date/Time] IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Originally, in the sub query FORMAT(b.[Entry Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') and Format(a.[Transaction Date/Time],'dd-mm-yyyy') were used.
I made an error while copy and pasting.
Entry Date should refer to table alias a and Transaction Date should refer to table alias b.
I adjusted the original query, should work now.